# php8.0-fpm service not loading

Tags: php-fpm, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I recently upgraded from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.0. It seemed to work just fine until I rebooted. It looks like my PHP service isn't loading.

```
user@server:~$ sudo systemctl status php8.0-fpm
● php8.0-fpm.service - The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2022-04-03 23:11:55 CAT; 8min ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm8.0(8)
  Process: 2628 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/ph
  Process: 2611 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.0 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.c
 Main PID: 2611 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Apr 03 23:10:25 server.net systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
Apr 03 23:11:55 server.net systemd[1]: php8.0-fpm.service: Start operation timed out. Termina
Apr 03 23:11:55 server.net systemd[1]: php8.0-fpm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Apr 03 23:11:55 server.net systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

This is a LAMP installation on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You need to check that rng-tools is installed: apt-get install rng-tools